# Decimal to Hex Conversion (Java)

Tags: java, hex, decimal

I wrote the following code to convert decimal to hex:

```
System.out.println("The decimal number you enter will be converted to its hexadecimal equivalent.");

    System.out.println("Please enter a decimal number: ");

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int dec = keyboard.nextInt();

    int input = dec;

    String hex = "";

    char dig[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};

    while(dec > 0)
    {
        input = dec%16;

        hex = dig[input] + hex;

        dec = dec / 16;
    }

    System.out.println("The decimal number you entered, " + input + " is " + hex + " in hexadecimal.\n");
```

The conversion works perfectly, but the output, specifically where the decimal input should be is not correct.  I understand that it is because I'm modifying the value in the while loop, and I am sure it is an easy fix, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to keep the code, for the most part, the way it is and display the original decimal value entered.  A nudge (I'm not looking for the answer) in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have modified `input` during your calculations, so it no longer represents what was entered.  Keep another variable for what the user entered that won't be modified, and use it in the `println` statement.

Comment: Thank you!  I just created in origDec = dec and used that in the System.out.println.  Thank you for your suggestion!